# Jquery apenas para mobile, é possível?

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse trecho do meu código que faz um scrool para a class **".abas"**

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".abas").offset().top}, 300);
```

Seria possível chamar a classe **.abas** no desktop e no mobile a classe **.abas_mobile**?

estou fazenso assim, mais não está dando certo

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".abas").offset().top}, 300);

$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".abas_mobile").offset().top}, 300);
    }   
});
```

Comment: É possível sim. Em tese, o site versão mobile deve ter o mesmo comportamento da versão desktop. O que não está dando certo?

Comment: com o meu código ele não troca de classe, chama a mesma classe no mobile e no desktop, quero chamar a classe .abas no desktop e no mobile a classe .abas_mobile

Comment: @RickPariz ficou ainda a mesma coisa, quero chamar a classe .abas no desktop e no mobile a classe .abas_mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que separar as duas animações para cada versão, e ainda usar `.stop()` para parar uma animação antes de começar a outra.

No exemplo abaixo, alterne o snippet para "tela cheia" para ver o efeito:

```js
$(window).on("load resize",function(){
   $('html, body').stop();
   var abas = $(this).width() <= 800 ? ".abas_mobile" : ".abas";
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(abas).offset().top}, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p class="abas">desk</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p class="abas_mobile">mob</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa fazer é criar uma função e atribuir "window.onresize = 'nome da função'" no final do script, deixei um exemplo criado para você [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorge10/nvjxvter/). Redimensione a tela do editor para ver o resultado.